# NSString isEqual strange bug

Tags: objective-c, json, nsstring

I have a web server which I used to fetch some data in my iOS application. The data include a field as the `itemId` let say `'48501'` (with no quotation). I read item JSON data into my `itemObject` in which `itemId` is defined as a `NSString` and not a `NSInteger`.

Everything works until this point but I have problems where I want to compare `itemObject.itemId` using `isEqual:` function with another `NSString` filled with `48501`.

In other words both string are exactly the same and include `48501` when I print them. No space and hidden things is there. All `isEqual:` and `isEqualToString:` and `==` report false on comparison.

On the hand when I convert `NSStrings` to `NSInteger`s and compare them it works but not always! sometime `TRUE` sometime CRASH with no error to catch and just pointing to the line! I see them printed exactly the same but the if statement does not go through.

I showed the code to someone with far more experience than me and he was like this could be a bug! Anyone has ever exposed to this?

Comment: Have you logged the length of both strings to ensure they give the same value?

Comment: I highly, highly doubt you are dealing with a bug. Sounds like you are doing something very very wrong. you need to log your comparison and post its output or post the code.

Comment: Are you certain after parsing the JSON object `48501` is a string and **not** an `NSNumber`? Trying to figure out what something is by the way it is printed to the console is not very helpful. Print the class as well. Quotes around numbers are often misleading.

Comment: The fact that your property is defined as `NSString` doesn't mean that prevents you to do something like this: `myObject.itemId = @1`. It will still log as `1` but its not an `NSString` its an `NSNumber` and that's why the comparison fails. Check that you assign a string from your JSON, or do an `NSLog(@"%@", [myObject.itemId class]);` to inspect the real class of the property after assignment...

Comment: Yeah, if there are no quotes around the number in its JSON representation then it will translate as an NSNumber.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `itemId` is `48501` without any quotation in the `JSON`, then it's deserialized as `NSNumber`. Probably that's the problem in the first place. Try logging the type of your `itemId` and use appropriately `-isEqualToString:` for `NSString` and `-isEqualToNumber:` for `NSNumber`.